# CORS error when doing a fetch call in theme app extension to shopify app server using ngrok in shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api-node

Error when accessing app server from shopify using ngrok address .cors error
is there a way of acessing through the store directly?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access an App from the front-end because yes CORS. Also, you cannot access your App because SECURITY! You DO NOT call your App from your theme App extension for the simple reason that your App is secure. Without an API secret key to verify, you'd be exposed to the world. On the front-end anyone can see your API key secret. Therefore you do not call your App from the front-end. If you need to make secure callbacks to your App, use the App Proxy.

Comment: Thanks, it's just I´m new to shopify and , I have my app server configured to work with my app, I just needed to post a request within theme app extension. Can you explain how to use the app proxy in this case, I'm trying to use it but no success.